# If anchor is clicked php

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo information on a page after and anchor has been clicked

```
<a id="anchor">Information</a>
<?php
if(?){
echo 'INFORMATION';
}
?>
```

Comment: I guess it will be better to just create a form submit button and use css to make it appear like a anchor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's where you might want to utilize AJAX. You can often approach it like this:

```
<a onClick="  $('#output').load('output.php')  ">click here</a> 

<div id="output"><!-- This is where the content goes --></div>
```

Then define the according PHP script `output.php` like this:

```
<?php
    echo $whatever;
?>
```

jQuery will then issue another HTTP request, invoking a PHP script, and finally injects it where you told it to (`#output` div).

Answer (score 1):

```
<a id="anchor" onclick="document.getElementById('information').style.display='block';">Information</a>
<div id="information" style="display:none"><? echo 'INFORMATION' ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use javascript here. PHP would need a page refresh to process your echo statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP (your httpd, exactly) doesn't know anything about anchors, you'll need to handle this with javascript. Try jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this in PHP I'm afraid.  PHP lives on the server and the page is on your client (browser).  In order to do something (other than go to another page) when some clicks, you'll need to use javascript.  Look at [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like this.

PHP works in the server side, therefore once the anchor information has come to the client browser, you won't be able execute any PHP code there.

There are several workarounds if you really want to achieve that.

i) Use client side JavaScript.

ii) Use Ajax to maker requests to server side and update page accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to show the information after clicking into a link can use the following code:

```
<html>
<title>lasdfjkad</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showhide(id){ 
        if (document.getElementById){ 
            obj = document.getElementById(id); 
            if (obj.style.display == "none"){ 
                obj.style.display = ""; 
            } else { 
                obj.style.display = "none"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:showhide('abc');">Show/Hide Details</a>

<div id="abc" style="display:none;">
    your codes......
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The real beauty of Javascript.....Hope this help you